# Dynamic 3D Array not working on my class (will using vectors be better?)

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, vector

I have created a class that works for a static array, but when I try to use it with my dynamic array, it is not working. (To not fill this page with a long long code, I just copied one function of my class)

I think that my dynamic array is not properly created, but I am not sure of where I am wrong.

Even thou here I am just using arrays of 10 X 10 x 4 in my project i will need to use arrays of around 1500 X 1500 X 4. Is my approach accurate or would using vectors be better, if so, how can I implement it??

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
const int N = 10;
const int M = 10;
const int O = 4;
const double gama =1.4;


class Fluid
{
public:

    void SetInitialConditions(double *** Array_U, int initialX, int finalX, int initialY, int finalY, double rho, double u, double v, double p)  // initial conditions
    {
        for (int i = initialX; i<=finalX; i++)
            for (int j = initialY ; j<=finalY; j++) {
                Array_U[i][j][0]=rho;
                Array_U[i][j][1]=rho*u;;
                Array_U[i][j][2]=rho*v;
                Array_U[i][j][3]= (p/(gama-1)) + 0.5*rho*(u*u+v*v);

            }

        }
};
int main ()
{
    double ***my3dArray = new double**[M];
    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        my3dArray[i] = new double *[N];
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            my3dArray[i][j] = new double[O];
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k< O; k ++) {
                my3dArray[i][j][k] = NULL;
            }
        }
    }


    Fluid test;
    test.SetInitialConditions(my3dArray, 0, M, 0, N, 0, 1, 2, 3);
    std::cout << my3dArray[1][1] << my3dArray [2][2] << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: I stopped reading at `double ***`

Comment: Yes, vectors will be better.

Comment: @FredOverflow Can you explain why you stop reading there? I think that I can learn of my mistakes if You point them out to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be this:

```
for (int i = initialX; i<=finalX; i++)
        for (int j = initialY ; j<=finalY; j++) {
```

You are writing beyond the boundaries of the array.  Use <, not <=

```
    for (int i = initialX; i<finalX; i++)
        for (int j = initialY ; j<finalY; j++) {
```

However having said that, a vector would be much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

```
const int N = 10;
const int M = 10;
const int O = 4;
```

If `N` and `O` are indeed constants, you can allocate the 3D array in one big chunk:

```
double (*my3dArray)[N][O] = new double[M][N][O];
// ...
delete[] my3dArray;
```

This will be more efficient, both in regards to memory consumption and execution time.

You can find more information than you would ever want to know about multidimensional arrays [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c/4810676#4810676).